# Cleansing an excel spreadsheet with whitespace cells

Tags: r, excel-2003, tidyr

I'm looking for advice about how to cleanse an excel spreadsheet using R.

http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/5506.02012-13?OpenDocument

Gathering the years by `tidyr::gather` is simple enough. The difficulty is the subgroups. The groups are defined by whitespace. Each amount of whitespace is a subgroup.

[image]

My question is how to assign each row to its group, so that the table is tidy form.

[image]

My initial instinct was to look where there is a line of `NA`s in the spreadsheet and use `na.locf` to fill them, but that method cannot distinguish between subgroups followed by groups without subgroups. **Is there a way to count the amount of whitespace visible before the cells** in the linked excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

On the particular sheet you are talking about, there aren't any leading characters - the indentation is just the formatting applied to the cell, in much the same way as you might apply a font to a cell.

The only way to count the indents in the formatting is to create a macro . Here's a user defined function that will work:

```
Public Function inds(r As Excel.Range) As Integer
    inds = r.Cells(1, 1).IndentLevel
End Function
```

You would then just count the indents with =inds(a3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be trying to prepare the data for a pivot table (there might be better options). However to count the leading spaces, simple formula:

=len(a3)-len(trim(a3))+1

Comment: Hi, the formula gives the same value (1) for all cells. The leading spaces appear to be quite obscure, except cosmetically.